# Quota exceeded - uploading YouTube link from my app - not seeing exceeded quota on dashboard

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am trying to upload a YouTube video on my project - when I use the youtube api key for the project I am getting this error

```
{
    "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your \u003ca href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\"\u003equota\u003c/a\u003e.",
    "domain": "youtube.quota",
    "reason": "quotaExceeded"
  }
```

My boss tried posting to the same project with a different api key and it worked as expected - I am not sure what the issue is with the first api key - we are posting other videos using the same key - I am not seeing anywhere on the dashboard that I am exceeding the quota limit. Thanks Osha

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. Afterwards, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63565437/edit) your post, adding to it relevant missing information (without which the other SO users cannot come to your help).

Comment: Your boss couldn't have succeeded uploading any video *using a different API key*, because employing the [`Videos.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) API endpoint [requires proper authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#auth).

By no means an API key by itself could allow one to upload any video. The mentioned API endpoint requires an [*access token*](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) to be passed on to it and that access token must be valid.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - we ran this curl request to query the data about a public video : curl --url 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,player,status,contentDetails&fields=items&maxResults=1&id=xxxxxxx&key=xxxxxxx'  we ran it with two different keys - one returned the posted error above the second returned data about the video(as expected). I am not seeing on the dashboard where we are exceeding the quota.

Comment: Well that is not *video uploading*, but is an invocation of the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint. When called via an API key, this endpoint provides only public meta-data attached to the video of which ID was passed on through the parameter [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#id).

Comment: Do note that when an API endpoint responds with an [`quotaExceeded`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#gdata.CoreErrorDomain-quotaExceeded-quotaExceeded) error, it means that indeed you (i.e. the API key that represents you) exceeded the quota allocated. Even if two users (possibly using different computers) run the very same program (application), the quota accounting that's done by the API backend *is relative to the very key* that the API endpoint invocating URL contains. Same program, different API keys implies separate quota accounting.

Comment: On the other hand, if -- upon double-checking the data shown by your Google developers console -- you still see that the project that's relative to the API key producing `quotaExceeded` errors displays an actual quota consumption not exceeding the allocated limits, then you have to contact Google directly [for to report to them this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: Thanks, so it sounds like I need to apply for an increase in quota

Comment: I cannot assess whether you really need  to increase your quota (since know nothing about you and your app habits w.r.t. invoking API endpoints; the API endpoints do have quite varying [quota costs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost)). Do take into account that you may well [apply for a quota increase](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form), but,  according to the experience of users of this forum, Google's response doesn't necessarily arrive shortly.